# Label text not displaying correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

```
Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
    lblNumber.Text = ""
    strLttrInput = InputBox("Please enter a letter or phrase:", "Find the corrresponding number to the letter(s)")
    With strLttrInput
        .ToLower()
        .Trim()
    End With
    intPhraseIndx = strLttrInput.Length - 1
    Dim strWord(intPhraseIndx) As String
    Dim strOutput As String = String.Empty

    For intCount = 0 To intPhraseIndx
        strWord(intCount) = strLttrInput.Substring(intCount)
    Next

    For intCount = 0 To intPhraseIndx
        Select Case strWord(intCount)
            Case "a", "b", "c"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "2"
            Case "d", "e", "f"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "3"
            Case "g", "h", "i"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "4"
            Case "j", "k", "l"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "5"
            Case "m", "n", "o"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "6"
            Case "p", "r", "s"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "7"
            Case "t", "u", "v"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "8"
            Case "w", "x", "y"
                lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "9"
        End Select

        If strWord(intCount) = "q" Then
            lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "q"
        End If
        If strWord(intCount) = "z" Then
            lblNumber.Text = lblNumber.Text & "z"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

for example, when I enter "adgj", the label's text should be "2345", but when I run it, the label's text is "2"

Comment: using visual studio 2017 for vb. i forgot to remove that line, was trying many things to get it to work.

Comment: String.SubString() does not work the way you think it does.  Easy to see with the debugger btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is failing, is because on your substring, you are not limiting the length to 1. This means that the contents of strWord will be:

```
strWord(0) = adgj
strWord(1) = dgj
strWord(2) = gj
strWord(3) = j
```

You can fix this by specifying the length for your substring:

```
strWord(intCount) = strLttrInput.Substring(intCount, 1)
```

As a sidenote, there is no need to loop twice and store the letters, you could just do this:

```
For intCount = 0 To intPhraseIndx
    Select Case strLttrInput.Substring(intCount, 1)
        ...
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: ah, thanks for the help............i always end up overthinking and that almost always leads to redundancies and not being able to think straight

Comment: I'm not sure that is related to the code above, since the message states that you cant convert string to boolean, which is not happening here. You can turn option strict to off if you want in the Project Properties -> Compile settings